# Why does byte cast blow up inconsistently golang?

Tags: go, binary, byte, bitwise-operators

I have the following example, taken from the Addison-Wesley Golang book, which I have modified slightly:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// pc[i] is the population count of i.
var pc [256]byte

func init() {
    for i := range pc {
        pc[i] = pc[i/2] + byte(i&1)
    }
}

// PopCount returns the population count (number of set bits) of x.
func PopCount(x uint64) int {
    fmt.Printf("Value is %d\n", x)
    fmt.Printf("byte(%d>>(0*8)) is %d\n", x, byte(x>>(0*8)))
    y := byte(x>>(0*8))
    return int(pc[y] +
        pc[byte(x>>(1*8))] +
        pc[byte(x>>(2*8))] +
        pc[byte(x>>(3*8))] +
        pc[byte(x>>(4*8))] +
        pc[byte(x>>(5*8))] +
        pc[byte(x>>(6*8))] +
        pc[byte(x>>(7*8))])
}
func main() {
    // fmt.Println(byte(256>>(0*8)))  // This blows up, but doesn't blow up on line 19 or line 20, why?
    fmt.Println(PopCount(256))
}
```

Here's the same code in the playground: [example-code](https://play.golang.org/p/bL3BKvuU6R)
Just in case the link expires, here's the playground where you can paste the above and play: [go playground](https://play.golang.org/)

If you uncomment

```
// fmt.Println(byte(256>>(0*8)))
```

You get an error:

```
prog.go:31: constant 256 overflows byte
```

Given this is done inside PopCount without blowing up, I don't understand what's going on. Can someone help explain why it blows up when I do it in main but not in the function PopCount?

I dare say I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The is because `256>>(0*8)` (equivalent to `256`), is an untyped constant, which is too large to fit in a `byte` The rules in the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) state

> A constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:
>
> - x is representable by a value of type T.
> - x is a floating-point
>     constant, T is a floating-point type, and x is representable by a
>     value of type T after rounding using IEEE 754 round-to-even rules, but
>     with an IEEE -0.0 further rounded to an unsigned 0.0. The constant
>     T(x) is the rounded value.
> - x is an integer constant and T is a string
>     type. The same rule as for non-constant x applies in this case.

Inside your `PopCount` function, the `256` value is of type `uint64`, which can be converted to a `byte`, truncating it to `0`.

Comment: gore> var x uint64 = 256
gore> byte(x)
0x0
As an example in gore

Comment: @Jake_Howard: not sure what that means, or if you're disagreeing or not.

Comment: apologies, I should have been more clear. Gore is a repl for go, that is two lines of input and the output which proves what you said, thought it might help someone out to play with it and prove to themselves it works.